# How to quiz data from a json file

Tags: jquery, json

I am making a quiz to learn javascript (jquery) and I've come along way. Prior, I used just an object to store all the questions. I've "stringified" this object to JSON format and I'm using this code to retrieve it:

```
var question;
 $.getJSON('package.json', function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key, value){
        question = value[currentQuestion].question;
        var choices = value[currentQuestion].choices;
        var correctAnswer = value[currentQuestion].correctAnswer;
        var indexAnswer = value[currentQuestion].choices[correctAnswer];
     });
});
```

The problem is that I cant use the global variable question in the each method to assign to the global "scope" (it says undefined). JSON is usually used to add all the information directly to the dom, but I am depended on the currentQuestion number which makes it very confusing to me.

Prior I used this code:

```
$questions.each(function (index) {
    var choices = allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[index];
    $(this).next().text(choices);
});
```

In which I statically added each question using the dynamic currentQuestion number.

I am kinda lost what the best strategy is for this quiz as I want the answers to added dynamically (I dont want this in my html anymore.

```
<input name="group1" value="answer1" type="radio"/><span></span><br>
<input name="group1" value="answer2" type="radio"/><span></span><br>
<input name="group1" value="answer3" type="radio"/><span></span><br>
<input name="group1" value="answer4" type="radio"/><span></span><br>.
```

I dont want you to code it for me, I just want some pointers/tips as to what I need to make this work. The main question is how I can use JSON and jQuery in such a way that it dynamically adds the questions to the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the json-object using the foreach-loop.
Within this loop you overwrite the question variable each iteration, which seems pretty pointless.

Apart from that though: the "undefined" is probably not about the question-variable, but about the currentQuestion-variable. The currentQuestion variable is undefined and should be key instead.

Or you could change the $.each line to the following:

```
$.each(data, function(currentQuestion, value){
```

I think that would (partially) fix your code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by doing this:

```
function getJson(url) {
        return JSON.parse($.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'package.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            global: false,
            async:false,
            success: function(data) {
                return data;
            }
        }).responseText);
    }

    var myJsonObj = getJson('myjsonurl');


    var allQuestions = myJsonObj.allQuestions;
```

Now the entire JSON file has been automatically converted to a javascript ojbect, which I assigned to the variable of AllQuestions. I didnt need the AJAX call to be async since the data will never change during the session of the user.